# Quantum physics: Probability of first state using dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, probability

I am struggling with this question.
Let a two-dimensional Hilbert space H has orthonormal basis vectors |A⟩ and |B⟩. Consider a vector
in H ⊗ H:
$ |v⟩ = α_1 |AA⟩ + α_2 |AB⟩ + α_3 |BA⟩ + α_4 |BB⟩$ .

What is the probability to find the first system in state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|A⟩ + |B⟩)$?

---

I have tried defining the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|A⟩ + |B) = |a⟩$ and then using dirac notation to get $⟨a||v⟩ = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(α_1 + α_2)  + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(α_3 + α_4)|^2$. But this assumes that the braket operation acts only on the first state which I am not sure about, as well as just being wrong.

Provided solution says that you should define |a⟩ and then apply it like this (Not explaining what it does, only gives answer after it):

$|⟨a| ⊗ ⟨A||v⟩|^2 + |⟨a| ⊗ ⟨B||v⟩|^2$

Can someone explain to me what this operation does and how it works?

Comment: The result should be $\langle v|\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |A\rangle +|B\rangle \right) \right) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \langle A|+\langle B| \right) \right) \otimes I|v\rangle$. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Projective_measurement:~:text=them%20whenever%20possible.-,Projective%20measurement,-%5Bedit%20source) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of
$$
|a\rangle \otimes|A\rangle 
$$
I will more briefly write $|a\,A\rangle$ etc.

Your combined system is in state $v\in H\otimes H\,.$ Saying that the first subystem
is in state
$$
|a\rangle =\frac{|A\rangle +|B\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}
$$
is the same as saying that the combined system is in one of the orthogonal states
$|a\,A\rangle$ or $|a\,B\rangle\,.$

The probability that this is the case is clearly the sum of the two probabilites (since $|a\,A\rangle$ and $|a\,B\rangle$ are orthogonal). This probability is
obviously

\begin{align}
\big|\big\langle a\,A\,\big|\,v\big\rangle\big|^2+
\big|\big\langle a\,B\,\big|\,v\big\rangle\big|^2\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you for your clear explanation!